# Why $I_n\le log\left(2\right)$?

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Okay, we have $I_n=\int _{\pi }^{2\pi }\:\frac{\left|sin\left(nx\right)\right|}{x}$, and we need to prove that:

1)$I_n\le log\left(2\right)$    $,\:\:\:\:\:$  why just log(2) ? can not be 1?

2)$I_n\ge \frac{2}{\pi }\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{x}=\log(2)$ and $|\sin(nx)|\leq 1$ for all $n$ and $x$ hence $I_n\leq \log(2)$
B) $$\int_{a}^{a+\pi/n}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x} \geq \frac{\pi/n}{a+\pi/n}$$. Therefore $$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\int_{\pi+i\pi/n}^{\pi+(i+1)\pi/n} \frac{|\sin(x)|}{x} \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+i}\geq \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+i} $$

Comment: Right. But, as @Lucas mentions, $1$ is also a possible upper bound (since $1/x$ is bounded by $1/\pi$ in the given interval).

Comment: @AugSB That would be totally valid since $\log(2)<1$ but clearly $\log(2)$ being an upper bound is more restrictive. Lucas: $-1\leq \sin(x) \leq 1$, therefore $|\sin(nx)| \leq 1$

Comment: There you go, forgot about that one, my bad.

Comment: The definition of Riemann Integrals and the fact that $0 \leq |sin(x)| \leq 1$ for the first and the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \int_{a+im}^{a+(i+1)m}  f(x)=\int_{a}^{a+km} f(x )$ which is just splitting the region of integration of the integral up into $k$ equal pieces. If you've seen Lesbegue integration, that's another way of looking at it, if you haven't it's mot important.

Comment: @Archaick but why we have a sum in front? is from Taylor series?

Comment: It's saying the same thing as $\int_0^1 f(x) +\int_1^2 f(x)= \int_0^2 f(x)$. That is, if integrate from $a$ to $b$ and add it it to the integral from $b$ to $c$, it's the same as if I had integrated from $a$ to $c$.